# A package or any other way to merge multiple tiffs into multi-page tiff in the code

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, tiff

So I'm trying to make a service to merge an array of base64 buffers where each one is a .tif file, into one multi-page tiff.
For the record, I have seen "tiff-multipage", but it requires node-gyp which is not possible for me to install in my current workplace.
Are there other options?
Thanks